# How do you write this shorter?

Tags: if-statement, lua

I thought there was and better nice way to write this but I can't remember.
Is there an nicer way to write this in Lua?

```
if curSwitch == "shapes" then
  curSwitch = "colors"
elseif curSwitch == "colors" then
  curSwitch = "shapes"
end
```

Comment: `curSwitch = ({shapes = "colors", colors = "shapes"})[curSwitch] or curSwitch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works only if possible 2 values:

```
curSwitch = (curSwitch =="shapes") and "colors" or "shapes"
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this. 
Start with

```
oldSwitch = "colors" 
curSwitch = "shapes"
```

Then flip the switch with

```
curSwitch, oldSwitch = oldSwitch, curSwitch
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, I don't know `Lua`.

Usually, for a trigger, you use `XOR` operation.

Like, whatever `B` has (`0` or `1`), when you calculate`1 XOR B` it will invert the `B`.

`1 XOR 1 = 0; 1 XOR 0 = 1`.

You probably can create a `map` with `integer` (ideally, a `bit`) and `string` and put there `{0:"shapes"; 1:"colors"}` and then work with the number.

Or, you could just use a `true/false` for the `curSwitch`, then it'll look like this (ternary op):

```
curSwitch ? "shapes" : "colors"
```

But that's not that fancy if you repeat that everywhere.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement such a simple switch using a table.

```
switch = { shapes = "colors", colors = "shapes" }

curSwitch = "colors"
curSwitch = switch[curSwitch]
print(curSwitch) -- "shapes"
```

The problem is that if the value does not exist in the table you simply get `nil`.

```
curSwitch = "garbage"
curSwitch = switch[curSwitch]
print(curSwitch) -- nil
```

This can be remedied by an overloaded `__index` metamethod which triggers an error in the case of absent keys.

```
m = {
   __index = function(t,k)
      local v = rawget(t,k) or error("No such switch!")
      return v
   end
}

setmetatable(switch, m)
curSwitch = "garbage"
curSwitch = switch[curSwitch]
print(curSwitch) -- error!
```